# spring boot and BlockingQueue listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, listener

I have implement jms with spring boot, I am using @JmsListener to listen the topic

```
  @Component
    public class AMQListner {
        BlockingQueue<MessageBO> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1024);
        @JmsListener(destination = "${spring.activemq.topic}")
        public void Consume(TextMessage message) {
            try {
                String json = message.getText();
                MessageBO bo = ObjectMapperConfig.getInstance().readValue(json, MessageBO.class);
                queue.add(bo);
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want a listener that listen that blocking-queue, if it has value , then process. can we achieve this using annotation in spring boot ?

Comment: Do you specifically need a Spring-Boot solution? The pure Java implementation seems simple enough that I don't know how I'd expect it to be simplified by Spring Boot.

Comment: @daniu first looking for spring specific solution. otherwise need to use pure java implementation that not conflict with spring boot in any way .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the proper way is to create a handler bean instead of having a member with the message queue in the receiver class.

```
public interface MessageHandler extends Consumer<MessageBO> {
    public default void handle(MessageBO msg) { accept(msg); }
}

@Component
public class AMQListener {
    @Resource("multiplexer")
    MessageHandler handler;

    @JmsListener(destination = "${spring.activemq.topic}")
    public void Consume(TextMessage message) {
        try {
            String json = message.getText();
            MessageBO bo = ObjectMapperConfig.getInstance().readValue(json, MessageBO.class);
            handler.handle(bo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you would have the queue in the handler bean

```
@Component("multiplexer")
public class MessageMultiplexer implements MessageHandler {
    @Autowired
    MessageHandler actualConsumer;

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    public void accept(MessageBO msg) {
        executor.submit(msg -> actualConsumer.handle(msg));
    }
}
```

The Executor is pretty much the queue in this case.

Caveat: you do not have your 1024 limit in this way. You can do that by using the `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor and pass it a limited queue.

Comment: does `executor.submit(msg -> actualConsumer.handle(msg));` will resolve lambda expression ?

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor Not sure what you mean; it's a `Runnable` that will be run when the executor has a thread left for it. In this example, there will be four threads concurrently handling the messages; you can use `Executors.newSingleThreadPool()` to handle them one by one.

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor ... yes  lambda expression ```msg -> actualConsumer.handle(msg)``` will get resolved.